# Group Similar nodes in XML using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following XML structure

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root>
    <BookingGroup>
        <PostCodes>
            <PostCode >AB</PostCode>
            <PostCode >AL</PostCode>
        </PostCodes>
    </BookingGroup>
    <BookingGroup>
        <PostCodes>
            <PostCode >AB</PostCode>
            <PostCode >D</PostCode>
        </PostCodes>
    </BookingGroup>
</Root>
```

Now for every post code AB in the entire Xml I need the output as:

```
<Root>
    <Child>
        <Child1>
        </Child1>
        <Child1>
        </Child1>
</root>
```

because there are two AB postcode I need two child1 elements.

Comment: The question, as currently phrased, is incomprehensible.

Comment: I wonder if people ever *read* the stuff they write? No-one can *actually* be so handicapped *and* work with XML at the same time. But then again, maybe it is possible. http://xkcd.com/481/

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for that literal output, this will do

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:variable name="firstNode" select="//PostCode[1]"/>
  <!-- for a literal value use <xsl:variable name="firstNode">AB</xsl:variable> -->

  <xsl:template match="Root">
    <Root>
      <Child>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//PostCode"/>
      </Child>
    </Root>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="PostCode">
    <xsl:if test=".=$firstNode">
      <Child1>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      </Child1>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you are looking for a general solution that will output whatever nodes are in the input try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:variable name="firstNode" select="//PostCode[1]"/>
  <!-- for a literal value use <xsl:variable name="firstNode">AB</xsl:variable> -->

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="PostCode">
    <xsl:if test=".=$firstNode">
      <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```